# How to debug my React Recipe Box code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

I have been racking my brain trying to figure out the issue with my [React Recipe Box](https://codepen.io/MukeshAngrish/pen/WMLLjR). The project is on *CodePen*.

I've added a good amount of comments in the code to help you understand the structure of code as well as which part of the code is supposed to do what. [Click here to see the code](https://codepen.io/MukeshAngrish/pen/WMLLjR).

I'm making this project as a part of FreeCodeCamp curriculum. I'm new to React and fairly beginner level at JavaScript, so I might have made a silly mistake that I can't find. I'm also using Sass in this project.

Here are the issues I'm facing:

1. Buttons randomly don’t work (i.e., when I resolve the issue with one, say the button for add ingredient/delete recipe, the other button stops working, say the button for delete ingredient,  and a new issue arises from there).
2. If I comment few cases in the `modifyRecipe()` function of `App` Component the other cases start working fine. But not together. For example, If I comment first 2 cases, the last two start working.
3. After few iterations of resolving the errors, I find the same issue coming again which I had already resolved few hours ago.

The first error in the console you will probably find is the `this.props.deleteIngredient is not a function` inside the `deleteMe` function of the `Ingredient` Component.

The UI works like this:

1. Add new recipe by using big gold `AddButton`
2. Edit text by simply clicking the text itself. The text is horizonally scrollable
3. Add ingredient to the recipe with small add button in each recipe box
4. The delete buttons are accessed by clicking the pencil icon in each recipe box
5. There's an `x` after each ingredient to delete that particular ingredient
6. The `+` button at the bottom of each recipe changes to `x` when you click the pencil icon. It can then be used to delete that particular recipe

Comment: look at line 299 you need to bind that into the this.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing binding functions. please have a loo at line 259 and 260

```
this.deleteIngredient = this.deleteIngredient(this);
this.modifyIngredient = this.modifyIngredient(this);
```

to

```
this.deleteIngredient = this.deleteIngredient.bind(this);
this.modifyIngredient = this.modifyIngredient.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I wish I could say that helped but the core issues are still there. That was surely a mistake from me. I will remember to recheck binding of functions from now on. Thanks again!

Comment: Please see 97 line. you're overwriting `name` variable like this. `let name = name.name;` it's wrong because you can't overwrite parameter var. please change that like this `var newName = name.name` and 100 line `f(myRecipeBox[i].name == newName)` as well